# matrix multiplication in C - structures used

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, struct

I've searched for a similar situation but have drawn a blank so I'm posting my problem here:

```
void mtxmulti(struct matrix mAx, struct matrix mBx, struct matrix mCx) {
    printf("A * B:\n");
    if ((mAx.nrows == mBx.nrows) && (mAx.ncols == mBx.ncols)) {
        for (mAx.row = 0, mBx.row = 0; mAx.row < mAx.nrows, mBx.row < mBx.nrows; mAx.row++, mBx.row++) {
            for (mAx.col = 0, mBx.col = 0; mAx.col < mAx.ncols, mBx.col < mBx.ncols; mAx.col++, mBx.col++) {
                mCx.matrix[mCx.row][mCx.col] += mAx.matrix[mAx.row][mAx.col] * mBx.matrix[mBx.row][mAx.col];
            }
        }
        mtxpr1t(mCx); /*If successful, prints the matrix*/
    }
}
```

What you see here is my function to multiply two matrices together, however it crashes when I try to run it.

Other useful parts of the code:

```
struct matrix {
    int** matrix;
    int row, col, nrows, ncols;
};

int main(void) {
    struct matrix A, B, C;
    printf("Enter the number of rows and columns for A: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &A.nrows, &A.ncols);
    A.matrix = alloc(A.nrows, A.ncols); /*Allocates array*/
    /*. This part of code is 
      . just entering the values 
      . of the matrix*/ 
    printf("Enter the number of rows and columns for B: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &B.nrows, &B.ncols);
    A.matrix = alloc(A.nrows, A.ncols); /*Allocates array*/
    /*. This part of code is 
      . just entering the values 
      . of the matrix*/
    mtxmulti(A, B, C);
}
```

FYI: I'm being told that uninitialized local variable 'C' being used and because of this won't work. I hadn't needed to initialize matrix A and B, although I did allocate space for them as seen in the section above. The allocation looks like this:

```
int** all0c(struct matrix mtx) {
mtx.matrix = (int**)(malloc(mtx.nrows*sizeof(int*)));
for (mtx.row = 0; mtx.row < mtx.nrows; mtx.row++)
    mtx.matrix[mtx.row] = (int*)(malloc(mtx.ncols*sizeof(int)));
return mtx.matrix;
}
```

**EDIT**

I managed to solve the issue by just printing the answer. This therefore need not have to allocate space for matrix C.

Comment: You're being told *exactly* the reason for the crash. So... fix it ? (and unrelated, I see absolutely no earthly reason for `row` and `col` to be *members* of `struct matrix`.)

Comment: @WhozCraig but that's the problem, I'm needing the 'mCx' matrix to have  dimensions depend on 'mAx' and 'mBx' and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Its  [*matrix multiplication*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication). Given A as  `n x m` and B as `m x p`, the resulting matrix is `n x p`.. So.. allocate C as that size and do the math accordingly.

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @WhozCraig that's the issue that I'm having though? 'row' and 'col' are needed because they hold the value of the matrix element whereas the other two just show the length of the matrix.

Comment: Then what is the purpose of the `int** matrix;` member ? From everything I see both `row` and `col` members are used for nothing more than indexing, and that could be done using local variables. Sry, but I still don't see the point of them.

Comment: Try to investigate with debugger where program crashes. And explain рщц error appears (what message?). It can be a wrong memory allocation (we cannot see your `alloc` function) - check the values of `nrows` and `ncols` before allocation and result of `alloc` before using matrix.

Comment: @WhozCraig I understand that you don't feel that it's needed but I wanted to try do it through 'struct'  as I'm learning about them. Sorry if it's not what you would do but doing local variables doesn't change the fact that I can't solve the issue this way round

Comment: @KristopherRahimAfful-Brown this isn't beyond doable. If you have a function that **properly** allocates a matrix of a certain size, use it for A of size `n x m`, and B of size `m x p`, then multiplying them involves allocating a C of size `n x p`, then doing the proper loops to perform the multiplication. Your current code makes no such allocation for C. It needs to. Your current code improperly checks the row vs row and col vs col sizing of A and B. it should be checking that A.ncols == B.nrows. This needs to be fixed. What needs to be done is clear enough. It just needs to be done.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm sure you think you're helping me with the sharp way you're addressing my issue but you are not.

Comment: Then I guess I just don't understand what is it you *want*. You've been told where the problems are and  to fix them. What are you waiting for, someone to fix them *for* you?

Comment: @WhozCraig I just printed the solution because found it easier and less complicated.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand structure's fields `row`, `col` are used as counters... so you can do it, but when you initialize them and use in condition be careful:

instead

```
  for (mAx.row = 0, mBx.row; mAx.row < mAx.nrows, mBx.row < mBx.nrows; mAx.row++, mBx.row++)
```

try

```
  for (mAx.row = 0, mBx.row = 0; mAx.row < mAx.nrows && mBx.row < mBx.nrows; mAx.row++, mBx.row++)
```

**EDIT:**

And read about comma operation in the [C++ references](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/)

Comment: I agree that the `for` loops with the comma operators are at least part of the trouble.  Be very cautious, though, about pointing C questions to C++ reference material.

Comment: C has the comma operator too, it's my favorite operator.

Comment: @Marichyasana : I know that C has comma (,) operator, but I cannot understand what value will be in `mBx.row` after execution of `mAx.row = 0, mBx.row` (it seems to be undefined value)

Comment: Actually questions is already edited, and this bug is fixed now